# Definition of homeomorphism is missing continuity of $f$ in metric spaces

Tags: general-topology

According to my notes:

(1) Definition of homeomorphism in topological spaces

A function $f:(X,\tau)\mapsto (Y,\tau')$ is a homeomorphism if $f$ is bijective, continuous and the inverse $f^{-1}$ is continuous.

(2) Definition of homeomorphism in metric  spaces

A function $f:(X,d)\mapsto (Y,d')$ is a homeomorphism if $f $is bijective and the inverse $f^{-1}$ is continuous.

**Why is the condition on  f being continuous missing from (2)? If it is implicit, why not dropping it too from the definition (1)?**

I recall  continuity of the inverse and bijectivity implies continuity of f at least in $\mathbb{R}$ with the usual topology, could it be that is missing?, why or why not?

Comment: It seems like a typo. Continuity is of course required

Comment: It is clearly wrong. Being continuous is part of the definition of homeomorphism.

Comment: @José Carlos Santos But doesn't continuity of the inverse and bijectivity implies continuity of f? at least in real functions with euclidean topology

Comment: Yes, but not in metric spaces in general.

Comment: @J.C.VegaO: The map $f:S^1\to[0,2\pi):\langle 1,\theta\rangle\mapsto \theta$ is a bijection, and its inverse is continuous, but $f$ is not continuous at $\langle 1,0\rangle$. (I’m using polar coordinates in the plane.)

Comment: @ Brian M. Scott why isn't it continuous there?  and why is the inverse continuous?. Don't I need the explicit expression of the function?